# When i call blob image from data base in while loop I get mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

when i run this code i get only one image and returns "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 error", I want multiple images in my page.
Here is my code,

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","education");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from ep_posts where id > '4' ");
$sql = "Select * from ep_posts where image<>''  order by ID ASC  ";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['post_title'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $des = $row['des'];
    $des = substr($des, 0,35);  
    $link =  $siteurl."?p=".$id;    
    $sth = $con->query($sql);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

    $image =  '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'" height="150" width="150" >';

}
?>
```

help needed

Comment: `var_dump($result)` before the while loop. What do you get? Then, have a look at [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) docs to show you the error.

Comment: after doing  var_dump($result) i got this


object(mysqli_result)#250 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(32) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(4) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Hang on, it's because you overwrite `$result` inside your loop that's screwing it up. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Come to that if the first query selects all `*` columns form `ep_posts` the second query makes very little sense as it then selects all rows from `ep_posts`.

Comment: Ohh Thanks alot
but 1 more problem that it returns me same image for every post

Comment: What is the second query supposed to be doing it makes no sense as it looks at the same table as query1 but gets all rows i.e. there is no `WHERE` and you have the data from the first query

Comment: yes i knw it didnt make any scense but when i remove this query it returns me thie

Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string
that one is query  returns string and other mysqli_fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help.

Remove the unnecessary second query and anything that was using it. Then just change the image tag to use data from the first query result.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","education");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from ep_posts where id > '4' ");

// surely this is unnecessary
//$sql = "Select * from ep_posts where image<>''  order by ID ASC  ";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['post_title'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $des = $row['des'];
    $des = substr($des, 0,35);  
    $link =  $siteurl."?p=".$id;    

    // so these are unnecessary
    //$sth = $con->query($sql);
    //$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

    // so this need to use a column from first query result
    // so change $result['image'] to $row['image']
    $image =  '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'" height="150" width="150" >';

}
?>
```